# how can I extract a sublayout to match a subgraph in R

Tags: r, plot, layout, igraph

I'm using igraph in R, trying to extract a subgraph that comprises only the largest cliques in a graph.  I want to plot the graph and the subgraph (1) without moving the vertices and (2) while maintaining numbering.  I can't seem to make it work. I tried storing the layout coordinates directly in the vertices but plot seems to rescale things. Setting rescale=FALSE didn't work either. Here's what I have, first plotting the random graph, then highlighting the largest cliques, and finally displaying *only* the largest cliques:

```
# plot random graph
g <- sample_gnp(n=30, p=.1)
l=layout_with_fr(g)
V(g)$x <- l[,1]
V(g)$y <- l[,2]
V(g)$id <- 1:vcount(g)
plot(g,vertex.size=6,vertex.label.dist=1,vertex.label=V(g)$id,main="a random network",sub="where are the cliques?")

# highlight largest cliques
lc=unlist(largest_cliques(g))
vcol <- rep("grey80", vcount(g))
vcol[unlist(lc)] <- "gold"
plot(g, vertex.size=6,vertex.color=vcol,vertex.label.dist=1,vertex.label=V(g)$id,main="here they are!",
     layout=l)

# plot only the largest cliques, without changing position or vertex numbers
sg = induced_subgraph(g,lc)
sl = cbind(V(sg)$x,V(sg)$y)
plot(sg,vertex.size=6,vertex.label.dist=1,vertex.label=V(sg)$id,vertex.color="gold",
     layout=sl)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you did not set the random seed, so each time you run this code you will get a different graph and layout. I am setting the seed for reproducibility.

```
# plot random graph
set.seed(2021)
g <- sample_gnp(n=30, p=.1)
l=layout_with_fr(g)
V(g)$x <- l[,1]
V(g)$y <- l[,2]
V(g)$id <- 1:vcount(g)

# highlight largest cliques
lc=unlist(largest_cliques(g))
vcol <- rep("grey80", vcount(g))
vcol[unlist(lc)] <- "gold"
```

There are other ways to do this,  but I will do it using `rescale=F`.
When you do that, you have to adjust xlim and ylim to the ranges of the layout. Also,  it changes the scale, so you need to change the vertex size.
Putting all of that together, I get:

```
Rx =range(l[,1])
Ry =range(l[,2])
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(g, vertex.size=45,vertex.color=vcol,vertex.label.dist=1,
    vertex.label=V(g)$id,main="here they are!", layout=l, 
    rescale=F, xlim=Rx, ylim=Ry)


# plot only the largest cliques, without changing position or vertex numbers
sg = induced_subgraph(g,lc)
sl = cbind(V(sg)$x,V(sg)$y)
plot(sg,vertex.size=45, vertex.label.dist=1,vertex.label=V(sg)$id,vertex.color="gold",
     layout=sl, rescale=F, xlim=Rx, ylim=Ry, main="Unmoved")
```

[image: Graphs with large clique highlighted and just the clique]

Comment: thank you! That works beautifully. I'm only surprised that igraph hasn't provided an  easier way to do something so basic. It required some experimentation to readjust the vertex sizes and label distances so everything stays readable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `set-vertex_attr` to set the `name` attribute for graph `g`, and then subset the layout `lc` like below

```
# plot random graph
set.seed(2021)
g <- sample_gnp(n = 30, p = .1)
l <- layout_with_fr(g)
# highlight largest cliques
lc <- unlist(largest_cliques(g))


g %>%
  set_vertex_attr(name = "name", value = seq(vcount(.))) %>%
  induced.subgraph(lc) %>%
  plot(layout = l[as.integer(names(V(.))), ], vertex.color = "gold")
```

and you will get

[image]